# Event listener for undo in browsers

Tags: javascript, dom, events, dom-events, undo

To give context, my team is building a **rich text editor** in the browser that needs to persist state to a server between sessions. The editor's state can obviously change from updates to the document that include keydown events, but we should also account for **updates to the editor's stage that are triggered by undo/redo events**.

Unfortunately the browser has **no native undo/redo events** ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)). One proposed [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36974808/asking-for-undo-redo-events-in-html-javascript) floating around seems to be to stop propagation for keydown events that maps to undo's keyboard shortcut in addition to disabling the context menu. *However*, this still leaves open the ability for the user to **navigate directly to `Edit -> Undo` in the application's menu bar**, which will directly trigger a `document.execCommand('undo')` and doesn't fire an event. As a result we wouldn't know to send an update to the server.

Here's a W3C [thread](https://github.com/w3c/editing/issues/150) on this issue. As of the writing of this, it appears that a solution is still in the works...

When [Quill](https://quilljs.com/), another browser text editor, ran into this issue their team seemed to [advise](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/588): "disable the native undo/stack", which is what Facebook's [Draft.js](https://draftjs.org/) actually [does](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/67c5e69499e3b0c149ce83b004872afdf4180463/src/component/handlers/edit/commands/keyCommandUndo.js#L24-L27). Given that seems to be what we're working with, does anyone know of a way to **disable/substitute the browser's native undo/redo stack**? Obviously, this is an aggressive solution, but, as of the writing of this, that seems to be the only option.

In the meantime, the answer to this question probably buried somewhere in the Draft's code. If no one beats my team to it, I'll report back on what Draft seems to be doing. Thought it was at least worth documenting this issue.

Comment: linked: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13319723/104380

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the best solution is to listen for a debounced `onChange` event from the `contentEditable` element. This doesn't allow for custom behavior regarding undo, but it should solve the main issue. Also adding a [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) event to alert the user to potential unsaved changes should handle additional edge cases.