# Is It Possible to get text of undo in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, undo, undo-redo

Is it possible to get the 'text' which I will get back on undo. For Example: I have two paragraphs

```
Para1
Para2 <--- deleting para2 using backspace
```

When I will do `ctrl+z` or undo , `para2` will be retrieved back. Is there any way in javascript to get that '**para2**' will be returned in the undo option (I want to get 'para2' in some js variable. I know it will come in editor automatically) ? Search a lot but didn't get any solution. Any help will be highly appreciated

P.S: I need this because I want to remove some attributes in my html on undo.

Comment: What element holds this `para`?

Comment: I very much doubt there's anyway to get that information for free, you'll need to do your own tracking. But it would help if you could be more specific: Is this in a contenteditable element? A textarea? An input?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516218/how-to-handle-undo-redo-event-in-javascript

Comment: Unless you dynamically load it into a var and then do something with it. CTRL-Z & CTRL-V / Cut and paste - is an operating systems feature and not a feature of any web language.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao  can be anything on which undo works. In my case its contenteditable div

Comment: It should work with normal `ctrl+z` right? Why need a JS function for this?

Comment: I think you can handle `ctrl+z` event. And I don't know, probably stupid approach: to compare old and new texts. The difference between texts will be the thing that user "undone"

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE 2

Due to OP's question changes, I will address this one last time.

> P.S: I need this because I want to remove some attributes in my html on undo.

### Undo **Retrieves deleted text**

### Delete **Removes text**

If you have a ton of attributes in your html, use the text editor's replace feature. What text editor do you use?

---

## UPDATE 1

Added a new function `getUndone()`. Do the following to test it:

1. Delete some text.
2. click the <kbd>⤺</kbd> button.
3. click the <kbd>Get</kbd> button.
4. The undone portion of text will be back as expected.
5. The undone text is also stored in a variable (i.e. `sel`).
6. The undone text is also in clipboard.
7. The undone text is displayed as well.
8. Used `execCommand('undo')` to undo.
9. Used `execCommand('copy')` to store in clipboard.
10. Used `window.getSelection()` to retrieve selected text and store in `sel`.
11. Used `.toString()` to display undone text.

[`execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) API is made for creating text editors. It has a ton of methods and properties. The following Snippet has `bold, italics, underline`, and `undo`.

```
 document.execCommand( 'undo',false,null);
```

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <style>
    body {
      font: 400 16px/1.4'serif';
    }
    #editor1 {
      border: 3px inset grey;
      height: 100px;
      width: 381px;
      margin: 10px auto 0;
    }
    fieldset {
      margin: 2px auto 15px;
      width: 358px;
    }
    button {
      width: 5ex;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 1px 3px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="editor1" contenteditable="true">
    The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
  </div>
  <fieldset>
    <button class="fontStyle" onclick="document.execCommand('italic',false,null);" title="Italicize Highlighted Text"><i>I</i>
    </button>
    <button class="fontStyle" onclick="document.execCommand( 'bold',false,null);" title="Bold Highlighted Text"><b>B</b>
    </button>
    <button class="fontStyle" onclick="document.execCommand( 'underline',false,null);"><u>U</u>
    </button>
    <button class="fontStyle" onclick="document.execCommand( 'undo',false,null);"><b>&#10554;</b>
    </button>
    <button class="fontStyle" onclick="getUndone()">Get</button>
    <br/>
    <label for='data'>Data:
      <input id="data">
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <script>
    function getUndone() {
      var data = document.getElementById('data');
      var sel = window.getSelection();
      document.execCommand('undo', false, null);
      document.execCommand('copy', false, null);
      data.value = sel.toString();

    }
  </script>
```

Comment: You haven't understood my question. I want to get the text which will be back on undo not the undo execution command

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The text in undo can be retrieved with an undo command. You said "In my case its contenteditable div" That's an example of undo text being retrieved on a contenteditable div. Did you try the Snippet? It's the blue button labeled *Run code snippet*

Comment: retrieved means retrieval in some javascript variable. Updating question with more clear explanation

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal see update. I believe I understood whatever you **said**, not whatever you **meant**.